# Old kernel version still running after several updates

Tags: grub2, kernel, updates

Currently running 3.11.0-18, but many other later versions are installed. For some reason the updates aren't getting selected for grub:

```
$ uname -r
3.11.0-18-generic
```

Listing kernels:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-18-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

I have noticed that my /boot/grub/grub.cfg actually does contain the newest kernel, just not at position 0. It seems like it is quite a mess actually (500+ lines), but it is what update-grub generates. How do I fix that?

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_RECORDTAIL_TIMEOUT="2"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=b
```

"
And also my grub.d directory:

```
$ ll /etc/grub.d/
total 144
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jun 28 02:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x 167 root root 12288 Jun 28 01:40 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  9424 Apr 11  2014 00_header*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6058 Apr 10  2014 05_debian_theme*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11608 Apr 11  2014 10_linux.dpkg-dist*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   694 Mar 18  2014 10_linux_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   172 Mar 18  2014 11_custom_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   694 Mar 18  2014 12_linux_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10258 Oct 10  2013 13_linux_xen*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1798 Jun 17  2013 14_memtest86+*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11531 Oct 10  2013 15_os-prober*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1426 Oct 10  2013 16_uefi-firmware*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   172 Mar 18  2014 17_custom_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Oct 10  2013 18_custom*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10412 Apr 11  2014 20_linux_xen.dpkg-dist*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1992 Mar 12  2014 20_memtest86+*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11692 Apr 11  2014 30_os-prober.dpkg-dist*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1416 Apr 11  2014 30_uefi-firmware.dpkg-dist*
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 18  2014 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 18  2014 proxifiedScripts/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Oct 10  2013 README
```

Edit:
Ok it is all fixed now. Turns out I had a messed up `/etc/defaults/grub` file and weird scripts in `/etc/grub.d/`. I restored those scripts from a livecd boot.

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in VPS?

Comment: No it is just my home machine.

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/default/grub` to your question.

Comment: You have a lot of scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` that are not common. How did they get there?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Is there an easy way to clean it? So that it is just like a fresh install?

Comment: I added contents of my `/etc/grub.d`

Comment: And is it Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Ubunutu Trusty 14.04.2 LTS. Hmm, I don't even have a 10_linux...

Comment: 10_linux should load the latest kernel.

Comment: You need to find default scripts and restore them.

Comment: I figured as much, but either it is missing or it got renamed. Is there a clean way to reset the contents of this dir to distro defaults?

Comment: There is no button "restore to distro defaults". You need to extract these scripts from installation media or re-install.

Answer (score 1):

The current kernel for LTS Trusty:

```
linux-generic-lts-trusty:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.13.0.55.62
```

To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

Make sure you also have `dkms` in some cases required like manually installed video drivers etc. To install it run: `sudo apt-get install dkms`

During kernel installation it should automatically update initramfs and boot configuration. After installation is done then reboot the system and after boot follow [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) to remove the old kernels from the system.

If you still not booting to the latest kernel then reboot the system and boot holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to get to Grub and pick the latest kernel to boot with. When booted run `uname -r` to be sure you do run the latest one then run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
```

Or follow *Pilot6* suggestion.

Comment: It won't help. Kernels are already installed.

Comment: ahh I didn't see the latest... will add more info then

Comment: I found the problem already. It is in grub config.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that a bunch of weird stuff had shown up in /etc/grub.d (no idea how). I restored it with the contents of the live CD of that same path. Also I re-installed grub-pc `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc` and let it overwrite the current `etc/defaults/grub` so that it all is normal again. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 0):

You manually configured your `/etc/default/grub`. That's why this problem appeared.

Remove this

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=b
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should be fixed.

The last line is crap. And GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER does not let to find new kernels.

There may some other hidden errors in that file. Here is the default one.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

You can just replace yours with this one.

I hope you know how edit system files using `sudo`.

This is contents of my `/etc/grub.d`

```
00_header        10_linux      20_memtest86+  30_uefi-firmware  41_custom
05_debian_theme  20_linux_xen  30_os-prober   40_custom         README
```

Comment: I did this, but then when I loaded grub-customizer to take a look at grub.cfg, the first entry still points to the old 3.11.0-18 kernel.

Comment: grub.cfg will be rebuit normally.

Comment: Yes, that is what happened. But it was built with the same old kernel version again. I imagine this might have something to do with the contents of my grub.d directory?

Comment: You made a lot of modifications to your grub configs. @pieter3d